Does Cross Database Support Microsoft Entra in Azure SQL Database?
I have connected Azure SQL with Microsoft Entra which do not required any Username and Password. But when i created Database scoped credential it is throwing error while querying external table query, although Credential created without any error. Is there any other way to get rid of Cross database issue Please help me.
I tried using Identity in Database Scoped Credential as Manage Instance without  secret then also it is throwing error.

Elastic queries are only supported when connecting with SQL Server Authentication. does not support Microsoft Entra Id authentication.

When ever I see the need to cross database queries in an Azure SQL Database my initial thoughts is that you are using the wrong product. If you need cross database queries then Azure SQL Database is the wrong choice; the databases are contained databases by design.

What will be the right approach to use Cross Database. Actually, we are using SP in SQL server on prem which contains cross Db queries but now shifting to Azure SQL then what should be approached to use those queries.

@Bhavani If Elastic Queries does not support AAD authentication what any approach i can use to resolve my issue?

According to the MS document,

elastic queries are only supported when connecting with SQL Server Authentication.

Microsoft Entra ID authentication doesn't support cross-database queries in azure sql database. You can use SQL Server authentication as follows:
Here, I am taking two sample Azure SQL databases, db and db1. Create a master key and scoped credential in the db1 database using the code below:
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<Password>';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL <name> WITH IDENTITY = '<userName>',
SECRET = '<Password>';


Create an external data source with the created scoped credential using the code below:
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <SourceDbName>
WITH
(
    TYPE=RDBMS,
    LOCATION='<serverName>.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME='<SourceDbName>',
    CREDENTIAL= <scopeedCredentialName>
);



Create an external table with an external data source using the code below:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[newstudent](
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    DATA_SOURCE = db,
    SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo',
    OBJECT_NAME = 'student'
)



Query the external table using the code below:
SELECT * FROM newstudent

You will be able to query the table successfully, as shown below:


Thanks for this but we are using Microsoft Entra identity as Authentication. Any suggestions for that how we can use there. Any other way

According to the  MS document Microsoft Entra ID authentication doesn't support cross-database queries in azure sql database. You can use SQL Server authentication.

Sorry for asking again. If we use SQL server authentication, then there will be user id and password which will be different for each users. Any way to keep username and password common for all users for specific project?

There is no such a way to keep username and password common for all users for specific project
